# The Lookup drop down is not displaying code with description after selection

Tags: acumatica

I have created a custom table with following fields and using it in grid for lookup. The following are the structure of the Table.

```
CREATE TABLE KcLocationColor
```

(
  CompanyID int not null,
  Code nvarchar(30) collate database_default,
  [Description] nvarchar(512) collate database_default,
  CONSTRAINT PK_LocationColor PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (CompanyID,Code) 
  )

I have declared the lookup using following statement

```
[PXSelector(typeof(KcLocationColor.code),
                  new Type[]
            {
             typeof(KcLocationColor.code),
             typeof(KcLocationColor.description)
            },
            DescriptionField = typeof(KcLocationColor.description))]
```

After selecting only code displays not with code and description

[image: Lookup]

I have used it with acumatica tables and it is working fine. I am not able to figure out the issue with custom table

Regards,
R.Muralidharan

Comment: Can you upload a simple customization project .zip containing just this screen and associated source to GitHub, Dropbox or Box? We'll review.

Comment: Working on a sample project. I will update the dropbox line as soon as possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set respective Grid Column’s `DisplayMode` Property to `Hint`.

[image]

At run time after selecting value from `PXSelector` it should appear as value - description

[image]